# What does this piece of python indexing code do

Tags: python, indexing

Please explain me what does this piece of code do.

h should be 32Byte result from sha256 calculation.

I am rewriting parts of this code for my project in C++ and I'm not sure if this switches byte order per 4byte chunk or change byte order on whole 32byte number.

```
def reverse_hash(h):
    return struct.pack('>IIIIIIII', *struct.unpack('>IIIIIIII', h)[::-1])[::-1]
```

And, how does this array index work ?

```
   [::-1]
```

Thanks for any and all info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[::-1]` reverse order of elements in a list, so this script change order of each 4-bytes subsequence (in order to change endiannes, I suppose):

```
>>> h = ''.join(map(str, range(0,21)))
>>> h
'01234567891011121314151617181920'
>>> struct.pack('>IIIIIIII', *struct.unpack('>IIIIIIII', h)[::-1])[::-1]
'32107654019821114131615181710291'
```

Equivalent expression:

```
>>> struct.pack('<IIIIIIII', *struct.unpack('>IIIIIIII', h))
'32107654019821114131615181710291'
```

Comment: Thank you, totally answered my question.

Comment: @user3153405 You're welcome. Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) appropriate answer if you feel your question is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

[::-1] creates a new list with reversed order of elements